# Denial of Service in react-svg-loader version 3.03 due to css-what?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, security, svg

React solution is showing one high vulnerability in npm-audit due to Denial of Service  in react-svg-loader version 3.03 due to css-what.

What is the possbile solution of the issue?

Issue is as shown below:

```
───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=5.0.1                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ react-svg-loader                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ react-svg-loader > react-svg-core > svgo > css-select >      │
│               │ css-what                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754                            │
└───────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replacing react-svg-loader with https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-react-loader. It does the same thing only we need to change the package and web pack config. It does not have any vulnerability as of now.